# what is the difference between ds:0x402000 and DWORD PTR ds:0x402000 in x86 assembly?

Tags: x86, reverse-engineering, disassembly, machine-code

[image: x86 assembly - intel syntax]

as you can see in the picture, i  can't understand the difference between **DWORD PTR ds:0x402000** and **ds:0x402000**. what is the syntactical difference between them. both fetches 4 bytes from 0x402000 and store it in eax and ecx registers. but why the syntax is difference?

Comment: but why the syntax is different? i tried using nasm and gas assembler. still they are     different.

Comment: [you should copy the text and paste here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: Please ***do not post images of screen outputs or of your source code***. Copy and paste the code into your question instead (edit the question), select it and press the `{}` button in the question editor toolbar to make it appear as code.

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference.  The load into EAX is using the short-form encoding, though.

I can't copy/paste anything from your crappy images of text, but notice in http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html that there's a special `A1` opcode for loads into AX/EAX/RAX.  For some reason objdump decides to omit the `DWORD PTR` in that case.

DWORD operand size is already implied by the registers, so it's not needed.

(We can tell this is 32-bit code, not x86-64, because that opcode would use a 64-bit absolute address in long mode, unless there's an address-size prefix.)